# How to test custom gradle plugin both with JUnit and manually in same sample project

Tags: testing, gradle, gradle-plugin

My goal is to have this project setup:

```
example-gradle-plugin
├── build.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com ....
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── example
        │       └── integrationtest
        │           │ # GradleRunner.create().withProjectDir(testProjectPath.toFile()).withPluginClasspath()
        │           └── SimpleProjectRegressionTest.java // 
        └── resources
            └── simple
                │   # plugins { id "example-gradle-plugin" }
                ├── build.gradle 
                │   # // includeBuild ../../../../example-gradle-plugin
                └── settings.gradle
```

So the folder src/test/resources/simple is both used from a JUnit test, but as well can be used to run gradle commands from the command line using the composite build approach.

So this should work

```
cd src/test/resources/simple
gradle build
```

And this unit test should also work:

```
    @Test
    public void testBuildSample() {
        final ClassLoader classLoader = ProjectSetupHelper.class.getClassLoader();
        final Path sampleSourceRootPath = Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("simple").toURI());

        final BuildResult result = GradleRunner.create()
                .withProjectDir(sampleSourceRootPath.toFile())
                .withArguments("build")
                .withPluginClasspath()
                .build();
    }
```

However, there is a caveat when running JUnit, the custom-plugin-sources are referred to in 2 different ways at the same time:

- `GradleRunner.create().withProjectDir(testProjectPath.toFile()).withPluginClasspath()` means to add project custom plugin files to the classpath for running the build during the unit test
- In `src/test/resources/simple/settings.gradle`, the `includeBuild ...` command also refers to the custom plugin.

Is there an easier or cleaner way to achieve the above: Having a sample project with composite build that can be used from the commandline to verify local changes to the plugin, and using that sample project also in a unit test of the plugin?

Currently in the unit test I copy the sample folder to a temporary folder without settings.gradle to avoid such complications.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but here is what I did.

I wrote a custom gradle plugin and was able to test it successfully with JUnit.

**MyCustomPlugin.java**

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler;

public class MyCustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project>
{
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project)
    {
        DependencyHandler dependencyHandler = project.getDependencies();
        dependencyHandler.add(JavaPlugin.IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIGURATION_NAME, "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0");
    }
}
```

**MyCustomPluginTest.java**

```
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.gradle.internal.impldep.org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MyCustomPluginTest {
    @Test
    public void testCustomPlugin()
    {
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
        // Java plugin required for IMPLEMENTATION task in the custom plugin
        project.getPluginManager().apply("java");
        project.getPluginManager().apply("com.mycustomplugin");

        assertTrue(project.getPluginManager().hasPlugin("com.mycustomplugin"));
    }
}
```

Sources:

1. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_tests_for_your_plugin
2. https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-create-plugin